# Getting raw data from a QuickFIX/J Message

Tags: quickfixj

I want to grab the raw message data from QuickFIX/J. That is not the string representation of the Message object but the actual FIX message data. They might very well differ due to the message dictionary that is being supplied to QuickFIX/J.

Now looking at the Message type we have

```java
private String messageData;
```

This is private however and is not accessible. On the other hand the toString() method looks like:

```java
public String toString() {
    this.header.setField(new BodyLength(this.bodyLength()));
    this.trailer.setField(new CheckSum(this.checkSum()));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    this.header.calculateString(sb, (int[])null, (int[])null);
    this.calculateString(sb, (int[])null, (int[])null);
    this.trailer.calculateString(sb, (int[])null, (int[])null);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

That being said, is there a way to get the raw data from the message? I can't seem to find a way.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was available to you in your QuickFIX/J version when you tried, but I can see it is available in 2.1.0 version.

In Message.java:

```java
public String toRawString() {
    return messageData;
}
```

Although, this method doesn't calculate body length & checksum after any modifications are done to the Message object. For that purpose, you have to use the toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to hack the engine to make a public accessor for `messageData`.